# What does "bail" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *bail* mean in the following remark?

> I had a female coworker, and she suggested that her husband and I play racquetball after work. My regular partner had bailed. So we meet up, play racquetball, and go back into the lockers to shower and then grab a beer.

Does *bail* here mean [to leave a place, especially quickly](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/bail_2), or [to leave a difficult situation](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/bail), or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the example, verb *[bail](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bail#Verb_2)* is being used more along the lines of  “To fail to meet a commitment” rather than either of the alternatives you mentioned.

Something I associate with *bailed* or *bailed on me*  or *bailed out on me* is being told at the last minute that the person can't make it. If they just don't show up, and don't tell you, they have *stood you up* instead of just bailing.  However, I don't know if that's a common interpretation of the connotations.

The sense  “To fail to meet a commitment” of *bail*, and the other senses you mentioned, ultimately stem (I think) from the following sense:

> `2.` To admit to bail, to liberate on bail; to release
>   (a person) from immediate arrest or imprisonment,
>   on security being given by one or more sureties
>   that the person so released shall be duly presented
>   for trial.  (From OED1's entry for verb *bail*; with cites from 1548 forward)

In a comment, J.R. suggests that *bail*'s sense of abandoning an obligation is associated with boat-bailing rather than with freeing from arrest, and provides a [collinsdictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/bail) link in evidence.  Note that that link makes no explicit connection between  boat-bailing and  obligation-abandoning, but merely includes a link to a *[bail out](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/bail-out#bail-out_1)* entry that includes the sense “(informal) to flee a difficult or dangerous situation”.  However, [etymonline's](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bail) *bail*  entry is very slightly more explicit; within the item that refers to boat-bailing it says: “To bail out "leave suddenly" (intransitive) is recorded from 1930, originally of airplane pilots”.
*Bail* (v.1, 1610s), as in to bail a boat, derives from nautical Old French *baille* “bucket, pail”.
*Bail* (v.2, 1580s), as in to bail someone out of jail, derives from Old French *baillier* “to control, to guard, deliver”.
Both Old French terms derive from Latin *bajulare* “to bear a burden”.

Comment: Does it make sense if I say "My partner had bailed on me"?

Comment: Theo, yes, but the briefer “My partner bailed” seems more natural to me.  Also, something I associate with  *bailed* or  *bailed on me* is being told at the last minute that the person can't make it.  If they just don't show up, and don't tell you, they have  *stood you up* instead of just bailing.

Comment: I've always thought that _"he bailed on me"_ was an informal way of saying _"he bailed **out** on me"_ and was more closely linked to _bailing out of an aircraft_ than _being liberated from jail_. Many [dictionaries](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/bail) I consulted linked this sense of _bail_ (i.e., to abandon a responsibility or obligation) to the word _bail_ as in [_bail out a boat_](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/bail_2) rather than [_bail out of jail_](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/bail). (Minor technicality, I know.)

Comment: Jwpat, you should add the distinction between *stood one up* and *bail* to the answer itself.

Comment: @J.R.- I agree with you. This usage stems from the aeronautical "bailing out"

Comment: @Jim, of course; but does the aeronautical bail-out term derive from  boat-bailing, or from freeing from arrest?  (As I pointed out in edit to question, both of those uses derive from Latin bajulare “to bear a burden”.)

Comment: @jwpat7- I tend to think it comes from boat bailing since I think bail (the jail type) is really the bond money, that derives from the french *baillier* (to guard) because the bail bonds man is essentially taking custody of the prisoner with the bail money as collateral.  I realize that they both ultimately derive from the Latin *bajulare* but they take separate paths.

Comment: @jwpat7 - I find it odd, too, but it seems to be the latter. That's how [NOAD lists it, too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UagNx.png).